# Uniformly bounded moments in time implies tightness?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the paper "Infinite time aggregation for the critical Patlak-Keller-Segel mode in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by Blanchet, Carrillo and Masmoudi. We have the PDE $$ \begin{cases} \partial_t n(x,t) =\Delta n(x,t)- \chi\nabla \cdot (n(x,t)\nabla c(x,t)) \\ n(x,t)=-\Delta c(x,t) \\ n(x,t=0)=n_0\geq 0\end{cases}.$$ At time $T^*$ a solution $n(x,t)$ blows up and [image]becomes a measure. They claim the following:
Let $n(x,t$ be a solution up to time $T^*$ and let $(t_p)_{p\in \mathbb{N}}\to T^*$.
 If the second moment is conserved $$\int |x|^2n(x,t) dx=|x|^2n_0(x)dx>0$$ and $$\int \phi_0(|x|^2)n(x,t) dx\leq C(T)$$ (tail control of the densities $|x|^2n(x,t)$ they call it) where $\phi_0$ is a convex superlinear function then the sequence $|x|^2n(x,t)$ is tight.

I have to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $K$ such that $\int_{|x|\geq K}n(x,t)|x|^2 dx<\epsilon$. In the paper they say it is by Prokhorov's theorem but I think that is used in the next step to construct a weakly convergent subsequence. Taking $\phi(x)=x^k$ I get that that all moments are uniformly bounded in time. Assuming the sequence is not tight I have there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $K<\infty$, $\int_{|x|\geq K}n(x,t)|x|^2 dx≥\epsilon$. I would like to get that then the 2nd moment would become unbounded. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify I write $\mu_t(d x) = x^2 n(x,t)\, d x$ for the measure at time $t$. I will show that if $\sup_t \int |x|^\alpha \,\mu_t(d x) < \infty$ for *some* $\alpha >0$ then the family of measures $(\mu_t)_t$ is tight.

Let $M \colon \! = \sup_t \int |x|^\alpha\, \mu_t(dx)< \infty$. Then, for $K >0$, we have
$$\begin{align*} \int_{|x| \geq K} \mu_t(d x) &\leq \int_{|x| \geq K} \left(\frac{|x|}{K}\right)^\alpha \, \mu_t(d x) \leq K^{-\alpha} M.
\end{align*}$$
Letting $K \to \infty$, we deduce that $(\mu_t)_t$ is tight.